# Jquery - check all events

Tags: jquery

I need to check these elements for all jquery events:

```
 $('#taskAdd, #unit_qtyAdd, #work_unitAdd').live('{all events}', function(){
   //some code here
   }
```

here is the full js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#taskAdd, #unit_qtyAdd, #work_unitAdd').live('{all events}', function(){
term1 = $('#taskAdd').val();
term2 = $('#unit_qtyAdd').val();
term3 = $('#work_unitAdd').val();
term4=$("#job_task_idAdd").val();
$.ajax({
        type: "POST", 
        url: "",    //the url
        data: "s1="+term1+"&s2="+term2+"&s3="+term3+"&s4="+term4,
        success: function(data) {
        $( "#estimatedAdd" ).val('').val( data );
        $( "#chargedAdd" ).val('').val( data );
        }
    });
    });
});
```

Anybody can help, please?

Comment: `.live()` is deprecated, use `.on()` and what do you mean with "check"

Comment: i mean, validate these elements. They are of different type( text, select)

Comment: Look at the livequery plugin, which is effectively a DOM listener, but watch out for performance with firing huge numbers of events on lots of elements, particularly within older browsers.

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to set an interval and check them every .1 seconds or so? would make the performance a lot better

Comment: I don't understand what you mean "check for all events"?  what are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to calculate the sum using some fields and display the result on other input text, calculated through jquery ajax post. I have different type inputs and i need to calculate the sum on all input fields changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I told you in the comment:

`.live()` is deprecated now, so use `.on()`.

For a validation I suggest you to use **[jquery.validate](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/)**

This is the basic usage:

```
$(form).on('click', 'yourSubmitButton', function() {

    $(form).validate();

});
```

---

If you mean data binding, to see what happen in real time in your fields, try to take a look at **[Knockoutjs](http://knockoutjs.com/)**.

Comment: i've written the full js code above. i don't need to validate the form. I need te make some calculations and see the live result on one other field

Comment: i changed it to: `$('#taskAdd, #unit_qtyAdd, #work_unitAdd').on('keyup change {some other events...}', function(){ }` and it works. Thanks